# displaying css files in inspect-elements magento

Tags: php, html, css, magento, frontend

Magento display the ways to all css.

allreviews.css is the last added style. If I add one more file, it will be displayed instead of allreviews.css in inspector. And  also add path. How to make the correct path to file is displayed? Please help...[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. It make the extension Fooman Speedster.